# Npm i ts-node-dev --save-dev leads to no such file or directory, chmod node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib\bin.js'

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, ts-node, ts-node-dev

I try to install ts-node-dev:

> npm i ts-node-dev --save-dev

And get the error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod
> '/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib\bin.js'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to open issues [#224](https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev/issues/224) and [#235](https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev/issues/235) in the GitHub repo.

The current suggested workarounds are either;

1. Updating npm to the latest version.
2. Or, install the earlier version `1.0.0-pre.65`.

   So you may want to try running the following command in your project directory:

   ```
   npm un -D ts-node-dev && npm i -D ts-node-dev@1.0.0-pre.65
   ```